# Google Script - Get filename from URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some URLs that redirects and downloads csv files. I want to get the filenames of the file. Is this anyway possible.

This is the code I currently use:

```
function importCSVFromWeb(csvUrl,rownum,sheet) {
  var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
var csvFileName =UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getBlob().getName();
  //Logger.log(csvFileName);
  sheet.getRange(rownum, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
sheet.getRange(rownum, csvData[0].length, 1, 1).setValue(csvFileName);
sheet.getRange(rownum, csvData[0].length, 1, 1).copyTo(sheet.getRange(rownum+1, csvData[0].length,csvData.length,1));
sheet.deleteRow(rownum);
}
```

PLease assist.

Here is a sample URL which downloads csv.

https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/spreadsheet-987656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can directly retrieve the filename from "Content-Disposition" of the response headers of `UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl)`. The value is `'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="20200213-bunbury-r02.csv"',`.

So how about the following modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
var csvContent = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getContentText();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
var csvFileName =UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl).getBlob().getName();
```

To:

```
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(csvUrl);
var csvContent = res.getContentText();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csvContent);
var csvFileName = res.getHeaders()["Content-Disposition"].match(/filename="(\w.+)"/)[1];
```

- You can also use `var csvFileName = res.getHeaders()["Content-Disposition"].split("=")[1].replace(/"/g, "");`.

#### Result:

In the case of `https://www.punters.com.au/form-guide/spreadsheet-987656`, `csvFileName` is `20200213-bunbury-r02.csv`.

#### Reference:

- [getHeaders()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getHeaders())

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks soo much. Worked perfectly. Cant thank you enough

Comment: @Joe Abraham Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.